# Check for IE 10

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-10

How can I make a message box appear on page load if the user is using IE 10?

```
function ieMessage() {
    alert("Hello you are using I.E.10");
}
```

My webpage is a JSF facelet (XHTML).

Comment: Why do you need to do this?

Comment: project for school, got to display messages in different browsers :)

Comment: [Browser detection in javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2400935/browser-detection-in-javascript).

Comment: Just a note--I know the world tells me that feature detection and graceful degradation are the way to go, but when it comes to using or avoiding ES6 (and eventually ES7) features, the usual stuff just doesn't work.  I can't use 'let' and 'const' and arrow functions on browsers that don't support them, and I want to start using them.  That leaves me with little choice other than to detect IEs 10 and 11, and use different scripts with them.

Comment: @RyanO'Hara I'm having issues with creating a custom scrollbar which you canät do apparantly in IE10 so...

Comment: @KarlMorrison: So…? If you can’t do it in IE10, will knowing that the browser is IE10 help you do it?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

The real way to detect this, without conditional comments and without User Agent sniffing is with conditional compilation:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var isIE10 = false;
    /*@cc_on
        if (/^10/.test(@_jscript_version)) {
            isIE10 = true;
        }
    @*/
    console.log(isIE10);
</script>
```

After running this code, you can use following anytime after:

```
if (isIE10) {
    // Using Internet Explorer 10
}
```

Reference: [How can I detect IE10 from JS when browser mode is IE9?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15819904/how-can-i-detect-ie10-from-js-when-browser-mode-is-ie9)

---

**UPDATE:**

To avoid minification of comments, you can use something like:

```
var IE = (function () {
    "use strict";

    var ret, isTheBrowser,
        actualVersion,
        jscriptMap, jscriptVersion;

    isTheBrowser = false;
    jscriptMap = {
        "5.5": "5.5",
        "5.6": "6",
        "5.7": "7",
        "5.8": "8",
        "9": "9",
        "10": "10"
    };
    jscriptVersion = new Function("/*@cc_on return @_jscript_version; @*/")();

    if (jscriptVersion !== undefined) {
        isTheBrowser = true;
        actualVersion = jscriptMap[jscriptVersion];
    }

    ret = {
        isTheBrowser: isTheBrowser,
        actualVersion: actualVersion
    };

    return ret;
}());
```

And access the properties like `IE.isTheBrowser` and `IE.actualVersion` (which is translated from internal values of JScript versions).

Comment: It would be a lot more annoying to test this in different IE versions, however.

Comment: @AlexW Not really. It's fairly easy to modify to get the IE version back (instead of true/false based on a certain version), and is actually reliable. So I'd rather use something that works and can't be spoofed than something that can change and be changed

Comment: Great answer, thanks. Could this be updated with IE11?

Comment: @Zubzob Yeah of course, good point! Would you do me a favor, since I don't have IE 11 (and don't want to upgrade to it yet)? Open up the Developer Tools and run `alert(new Function("/*@cc_on return @_jscript_version; @*/")());` - I don't want to assume the number is "11", but I'm guessing it and want to verify that before I add it to the list in my code.

Comment: It's undefined apparently

Comment: @Zubzob Interesting...and not good. Hmm

Comment: Note: I don't personally have IE11 installed either, I asked a friend to run that in the console.

Comment: @Zubzob Hmm okay. I'll see if I can get IE11 somewhere and try it myself (not that it would produce a different result, but I guess I should try)

Comment: IE11 does not support conditional compilation.

Comment: And what if in the future we reach jscript version 100?

Comment: @BenjaminBerger This question was for IE 10 specifically, not all versions of IE. It's already been determined that this doesn't work for IE 11 (off topic), as they removed support for conditional compilation.

Answer (score 34):

In general, the practice of User Agent sniffing and conditional compilation/comments are best avoided.  It is far better to use [feature detection](https://www.w3.org/community/webed/wiki/Optimizing_content_for_different_browsers:_the_RIGHT_way#Why_feature_detection_is_better), [graceful degradation](https://www.w3.org/community/webed/wiki/Optimizing_content_for_different_browsers:_the_RIGHT_way#Graceful_degradation) , and [progressive enhancement](https://www.w3.org/community/webed/wiki/Optimizing_content_for_different_browsers:_the_RIGHT_way#Progressive_enhancement) instead. However, for the few edge cases where it is more convenient for the developer to detect the browser version, you can use the following code snippets:

This `if` statement will only execute on IE 10

```
// IF THE BROWSER IS INTERNET EXPLORER 10
if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("MSIE 10") !== -1)
{
    window.alert('This is IE 10');
}
```

This `if` statement will only execute on IE 11

```
// IF THE BROWSER IS INTERNET EXPLORER 11
var UAString = navigator.userAgent;
if (UAString.indexOf("Trident") !== -1 && UAString.indexOf("rv:11") !== -1)
{
    window.alert('This is IE 11');
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Qz97n/

Comment: Amazing code! I have been looking for hours how to do this. +1 for including IE 11 too ;)

Comment: @Alex W, what need to be done to improve above solution to detect <= IE10 browsers? (Meaning IE10 or lesser versions)

Answer (score 20):

Here's a method for getting the current IE or the IE Version:

```
function IE(v) {
  return RegExp('msie' + (!isNaN(v)?('\\s'+v):''), 'i').test(navigator.userAgent);
}
```

Here's how you can use it:

```
if(IE())   alert('Internet Explorer!');
if(IE(10)) alert('Internet Explorer 10!');
```

Comment: where does v come from?

Comment: @Rhyso it's the parameter you pass into the function - in this case the number 10.

Comment: sorry should have looked at the usage example :)