# Difference between new Function() and new Function()()

Tags: javascript, function, constructor, parentheses

I came across some code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16135814/check-for-ie-10) where the Function constructor is called in an interesting way:

```
var jscriptVersion; // ...some code
jscriptVersion = new Function("/*@cc_on return @_jscript_version; @*/")();
```

At first I thought the extra parentheses were a mistake but after testing a bit in the console I thought maybe it was a shortcut to get a return value:

```
var a = new Function("return 'abc'");
var b = new Function("");
var c = new Function("")();
var d = new Function("return 'xyz'")();

console.log(a, typeof a);  // f anonymous() { return 'abc' } , function
console.log(b, typeof b);  // f anonymous() { } , function
console.log(c, typeof c);  // undefined , undefined
console.log(d, typeof d);  // xyz , string
```

I'm guessing `d` is (almost, aside from the `new` keyword) functionally identical to:

```
var d2 = function() { return 'xyz' }(); console.log(d2); // xyz
```

But again I've literally never seen trailing parentheses after a function expression that is not an IIFE, and I'm surprised that the code defining `d2` doesn't result in a SyntaxError.

I looked at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function) but couldn't find clear information on how this would be used.

And is this valid JS or does implementation of double parentheses vary across browsers?

Comment: You do that when you have a function that returns an inner function that is meant to be executed somewhere else.

Comment: `function() { return 'xyz' }();` _would_ be a SyntaxError, but `var d2 = function() { return 'xyz' }();` is not because it is evaluated as a function _expression_ instead of a function _statement_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trailing parentheses after `new Function` will immediately invoke the function. It's basically the same thing as an IIFE, except that the function that is called is dynamically constructed from the passed string - `new Function` returns a function, which is then immediately run if followed by `()`.

```js
var a = new Function("return 'abc'");
var b = new Function("");
var c = new Function("")();
var d = new Function("return 'xyz'")();

console.log(a, typeof a);  // f anonymous() { return 'abc' } , function
                           // because that is the function that was constructed from the `return 'abc'` string
console.log(b, typeof b);  // f anonymous() { } , function
                           // because the string passed was empty, so the function returned from new Function is empty
console.log(c, typeof c);  // undefined , undefined
                           // because an empty function, when invoked, does not return anything:
                           // x = (() => {
                           // })();
                           // x is undefined
console.log(d, typeof d);  // xyz , string
                           // because the constructed function's body returns the `xyz` string
                           // and the constructed function was invoked immediately
```

Any function that returns a function can have `()` after its invocation, not just `new Function` or an IIFE. For example:

```js
const makeFn = arg => () => console.log(arg);

const fnThatLogs3 = makeFn(3);
fnThatLogs3();

makeFn(4)();
```